# Vue 3 computed property returning undefined for state values

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

I am using vue3's computed property to retrieve data from the state like so:
`const userData = computed(() => store.getters.user )`.

I get undefined when I try to access the values of the computed property using `userData.value`. When I check my return object, I see that the data exists. When I try `console.log(userData)`, I see the data. I am using vue3's composition API. I do not know what I am doing wrong.

Comment: "I get undefined when I try to access the values of the computed property" - where? Please, provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for your problem